# Invalid block type: [Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Timeline

Tags: blocks, magento2

I've been trying to add a block to the footer but so far it keeps returning `Invalid block type: [Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Timeline`

The source of what I have so far can also be found here: https://github.com/sandermangel/magento2-twitterfeed

my `layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="footer">
            <block class="[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Timeline" name="twitterfeed-timeline" template="footer/timeline.phtml"></block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

and my block class in `vendor/[namespace]/[module]/Block/Timeline.php`

```
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Timeline extends Template
{

    /**
     * Timeline constructor.
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTweets()
    {
        // ---
    }
}
```

`composer.json`

```
{
  "name": "[namespace]/[module]",
  "description": "Lipsum",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "OSL-3.0",
  "require": {
    "abraham/twitteroauth": "*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/url.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth.git"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "[Namespace]\\[Module]\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

And the `exception.log` error

```
[2015-11-29 16:56:55] main.CRITICAL: exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Invalid block type: [Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Timeline' in vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:262
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(237): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance('[Namespace]\\[Module]...', Array)
#1 vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(216): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock('[Namespace]\\[Module]...', 'twitterfeed-tim...', Array)
#2 vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'twitterfeed-tim...')
#3 vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#4 vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#5 var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#6 vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#7 vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(166): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#10 vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(475): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#11 vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(433): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getElementAttribute('body', 'class')
#12 vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(159): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->addBodyClass('catalog-product...')
#13 vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(214): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View->initProductLayout(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\DataObject))
#14 vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Product/View.php(109): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View->prepareAndRender(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), 1, Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\DataObject))
#15 var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Product/View/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View->execute()
#16 vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor->execute()
#17 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#19 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#20 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'designLoader')
#21 vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/Design.php(39): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#24 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#25 vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 [internal function]: Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#28 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#29 vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 [internal function]: Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#32 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'contextPlugin')
#33 vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php(98): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 [internal function]: Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#36 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#37 vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(91): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 [internal function]: Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#40 var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Product/View/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#41 vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#44 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#45 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#46 vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(89): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 [internal function]: Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#48 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#49 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#50 vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#51 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#52 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#53 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCookieVali...')
#54 vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Plugin/StoreCookie.php(78): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#55 [internal function]: Magento\Store\Model\Plugin\StoreCookie->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#56 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#57 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#58 vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#59 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#60 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#61 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#62 vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#63 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#64 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#65 var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#66 vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#67 vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#68 index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#69 {main} [] []
```

Any idea on what might be wrong is appreciated

Comment: 'vendor/[namespace]/[module]/Block/Timeline.php' this path should be 'app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Timeline.php'

Comment: Do you have errors in logs?

Comment: @KAndy I've updated with the exception log. It's the error + backtrace

Comment: It means that your class cannot be loaded. Do you have you module registered in composer? Can you add composer.json.

Comment: @KAndy sorry for the late reply. Added the composer.json. You're right. It fails to get an instance in `Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block::getBlockInstance` but I wasn't able to determine why

Comment: is can also be cause by using the php extension in block definition xml by mistake...eg: `<block class="MyMod\ProductCategories\Block\Product\View\Categories.php"`

Answer (score 16):

I defined a `use` in the block class before the class definition. In this use I forgot a leading `\` which cases an error. But since that error is caught and suppressed in `Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block::getBlockInstance` it throws a completely unrelated error.

In short: causing a PHP error above the `class` definition will always result in the `Invalid block type:` error

Comment: I also had a similar problem now: I forgot to declare some "use" statements for some classes. The reported "Invalid block type" had nothing to do with the real problem. It took me a long time to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

To me was fixed when I changed the name of the file to the same of the class name and XML call. Like this:

**app/code/Rafaelcg/Smartlook/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Rafaelcg\Smartlook\Block\Code" name="smartlook" as="smartlook" template="smartlook.phtml"/>
 </referenceContainer>
```

**app/code/Rafaelcg/Smartlook/Block/Code.php**

```
<?php   

namespace Rafaelcg\Smartlook\Block;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Code extends Template
{
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Composer to include your module, here is another possible reason for that error:

You could have a wrong PSR-4 definition in your `composer.json`. Normally, it should look like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Namespace\\Module\\": ""
    }
}
```

However, if your module name is **not** `Module`, then your autoloading is broken and no class will be found. In this case, you need to fix the module name and run `composer require namespace/module` again to update the definition in the `composer.lock` and to re-generate your autoload files.